# Crystal Reports - "The report you requested requires further information"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have some Crystal Reports that were created using Crystal (external to Visual Studio) and are now loaded in the VS project. Before the report is previewed I set up the report database information like this in the report and all subreports.

```
        var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        connectionInfo.ServerName = "192.168.x.xxx";
        connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "xxxx";
        connectionInfo.Password = "xxxx";
        connectionInfo.UserID = "xxxx";
        connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
        connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

        TableLogOnInfo logon = table.LogOnInfo;
        table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logon);
```

The report displays correctly when it is initially previewed but when I go to the next page in the report preview I get the message, "The report you requested requires further information" and are prompted for the database login information again. Once I have entered it here I am no longer prompted. It appears that the initial ConnectionInfo I set up is not sticking past the first page.

I am using Crystal XI and Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the best way to fix a bug is to post the question to StackOverflow and 5 minutes later work it out yourself. Needless to say, I worked this out.

As well as setting all the log on info in the report objects, I also have to do it in the Crystal Viewer component in ASP.NET. So I just write some code like this and it all works, no prompts.

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer Height="500px" ID="Viewer" runat="server" />

var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    connectionInfo.ServerName = "192.168.x.xxx";
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "xxxx";
    connectionInfo.Password = "xxxx";
    connectionInfo.UserID = "xxxx";
    connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
    connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

for (int i = 0; i < Viewer.LogOnInfo.Count; i++)
{
    Viewer.LogOnInfo[i].ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
}
```

Comment: hi Craig, will you please elaborate this.Means i am new in crystal report and i also facing the same problem.where to add this code and how,please.

thanks in advance

Comment: @Craig.  I have been banging my head against the wall on this for some time and hope your fix works for me.  I can't tell from your code, did you put the var and for code in the CodeBehind?  Or as a javascript on the page?

Comment: It is in code behind. You might also have to recurse through subreports and set connection info on all of them as well.

Comment: why its now working for me?

var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                connectionInfo.ServerName = "XE";
                connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "";
                connectionInfo.UserID = "SO";
                connectionInfo.Password = "1234";
                connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
                connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

                for (int i = 0; i < CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Count; i++)
                {
                    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo[i].ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
                }

Answer (score 4):

Try to set the `EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt` property in the crystal report viewer to `false;`

Answer (score 3):

> Use Data Table instead of Data Set .. It works..

Answer (score 1):

put your coding to load event while bind report don't put  ispostback=false condition

*example*

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dt As New dsPrintRevisionStatus
    Try
        lblHeader.Text = Request.QueryString("name")
        If lblHeader.Text = "Report- Print Revision Status" Then
            Dim rpt As New rpt_PrintRevisionStatus
            rpt.SetDataSource(sqlHandler.ExecuteDataTable("SELECT * FROM [Print Revision Status]"))
            crtViewer.ReportSource = rpt
            crtViewer.DataBind()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblError.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but I found a simple solution. i.e. just replace `dataset` with the `data table` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the logon info as follows,

```
        LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "mcqueen";
        LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "abc123";
        LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
        LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "tbboss";

        crysViewer.LogOnInfo.Add(LogInfo);
```

simply put the  crysViewer.LogOnInfo.Add(LogInfo);  at the end of crystal Viewer parameter settings. Like follows.

```
    LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "mcqueen";
    LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "abc123";
    LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
    LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "tbboss";


    int exportFormatFlags =(int)(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.PdfFormat | CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.ExcelFormat);
    crysViewer.AllowedExportFormats = exportFormatFlags;
    crysViewer.ReportSource = Server.MapPath("Reports/Report1.rpt");
    crysViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;

    crysViewer.LogOnInfo.Add(LogInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt to see the actual error

Answer (score 0):

> Solved!.. If it is written in "Not IsPostBack" condition please remove from it. I solved this issue asp below snapshot. 
>   [image]

[Website link](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/119578/Crystal-Reports-The-report-you-requested-requires-further-information/)

Answer (score 0):

The future is nigh but Crystal Reports persists.

I was receiving this "error" from our crystal reports viewer.  My problem was a dynamically generated query that was being created with consecutive ORs.  The invalid SQL somehow elevated this "The report you requested requires further information" dialog box.

I fixed the query generation logic and do not see the dialog box anymore.